# Pymodbus getting address of slave

Tags: python, tcp, iot, modbus, pymodbus

I am working on a project where I am connecting two MOXA boxes to a raspberry pi. I am using pymodbus to connect to the device, and some LEDs are connected so I'm able to write to the coil and light them up.

I am using the code below:

```
import time
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient('x.x.x.x', port=502)
client.connect()

client.write_coil(2, True, unit=1)
client.write_coil(2, False, unit=1)
```

This turns the LED on and off, and if I increase the first number it lights up the next one etc. HOWEVER, the problem is that I cannot access the slave unit and its coils.

In the admin panel I have checked the "Enable Modbus/TCP Slave Protocol" but I do not have a unit ID nor address to the slave unit. The slave is connected to the master through an ethernet cable, and the master is connected to the network through another ethernet cable.

I have googled my brains out, but can't find where to get hold of the ID?

Comment: Are you able to see if the boxes are accessible outside of Python completely, via some other tool/utility etc?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to the modbus and log into the MOXA web interface admin panel and set modbus addressing. In the interface the "Enable Modbus/TCP Slave Protocol" is enabled, and I have given the box an IP-address to which I'm connecting to from the python script

Comment: Can you access it over Modbus specifically outside of Python, not just the web interface. I've never used Modbus, but taking I2C as an example I have used, I can check a device is there with `i2cdetect`.

Comment: I tried doing a nmap scan over the network, and it seems the only modbus activated is the master (or the slave), but just one.

Comment: What does the logs say? . If there is an option to view the debug logs of the slave, Have a look in to that and see if the request is reaching it.